# How to identify in a C# code if the request sent is from a Daily or monthly Job in Windows scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, scheduler

I have two jobs scheduled in a Windows task Scheduler. One is Daily and Another is Monthly.Both calls Same method.I need to identify in my C# code if the request i got is from Monthly or Daily process.
Is there a way to pass arguments to the request for the identification.
I need to add some new logic if it is daily report. I dont want to Create two different methods for these. I want to add this extra logic only based on the flag sent.Please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this (the Add arguments entry)?

[image]